# Help needed on a comparison table - How to break one cell into two rows?

Tags: tables

I need an urgent help in preparing a comparison table for a research paper. (I changed the names of some quantities.) The specific help I need is in the column for Parameter $C$. I wish to break each cell of the last column into two rows, one giving value for NPCR and the other giving value for UACR. Alternatively, the Parameter Column C can be broken into two columns, with one for NPCR value and the other for UACR value. I have no idea how to improve the look of this table. I like to change the entries of the last column into an attractive way improving the readability of the table. Thanks a lot for your great help!!

Code enclosed..

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Name of the Method & Parameter $A$ & Parameter $B$ & Parameter $C$ \\ \hline 
Proposed method & $p_0$ & $q_0$ & $NPCR: r_0$,  $UACR: s_0$ \\ \hline 
Method 1 & $p_1$ & $q_1$ & $NPCR: r_1$,  $UACR: s_1$ \\ \hline 
Method 2 & $p_2$ & $q_2$ & $NPCR: r_2$,  $UACR: s_2$ \\ \hline 
Method 3 & $p_3$ & $q_3$ & $NPCR: r_3$,  $UACR: s_3$ \\ \hline 
Method 4 & $p_4$ & $q_4$ & $NPCR: r_4$,  $UACR: s_4$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Place `\usepackage{array}` in your preamble; 2) change the last `c` in the column defintion to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}`.

Comment: (Since you said "urgent", please understand the above comment as a quick-fix. There are surely nicer ways to typeset the table as the anwers below suggest.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would indeed use two columns not two rows, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% because of caption above table
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
  Name of the Method & Parameter $A$ & Parameter $B$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parameter $C$} \\
                     &               &               & $\mathit{NPCR}$ &
                                                       $\mathit{UACR}$ \\
  \midrule           
  Proposed method & $p_0$ & $q_0$ & $r_0$ &  $s_0$ \\ 
  Method 1 & $p_1$ & $q_1$ & $r_1$ &  $s_1$ \\ 
  Method 2 & $p_2$ & $q_2$ & $r_2$ &  $s_2$ \\ 
  Method 3 & $p_3$ & $q_3$ & $r_3$ &  $s_3$ \\ 
  Method 4 & $p_4$ & $q_4$ & $r_4$ &  $s_4$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same can be done with math mode as part of the column declaration instead of explicit math mode inside each table cell:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% because of caption above table
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{l*4{>{$}c<{$}}}
  \toprule
  Name of the Method & \mbox{Parameter }A & \mbox{Parameter }B & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parameter $C$} \\
                     &               &               & \mathit{NPCR} &
                                                       \mathit{UACR} \\
  \midrule           
  Proposed method & p_0 & q_0 & r_0 &  s_0 \\ 
  Method 1 & p_1 & q_1 & r_1 &  s_1 \\ 
  Method 2 & p_2 & q_2 & r_2 &  s_2 \\ 
  Method 3 & p_3 & q_3 & r_3 &  s_3 \\ 
  Method 4 & p_4 & q_4 & r_4 &  s_4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

See the [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) manual for more information about using `>{…}` and `<{…}`.

If you additionally want a horizontal line between “Parameter C” and “NPCR UACR”, you can use `\cline` as usual and documented in several LaTeX introductions. As an improvement, you can replace `\cline` by `\cmidrule` as explained in the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual (available [in English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), [in French](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/translations/booktabs/fr/f-booktabs.pdf), and [in German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.pdf).

For the first example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% because of caption above table
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
  Name of the Method & Parameter $A$ & Parameter $B$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parameter $C$} \\
  \cmidrule{4-5}% added
                     &               &               & $\mathit{NPCR}$ &
                                                       $\mathit{UACR}$ \\
  \midrule           
  Proposed method & $p_0$ & $q_0$ & $r_0$ &  $s_0$ \\ 
  Method 1 & $p_1$ & $q_1$ & $r_1$ &  $s_1$ \\ 
  Method 2 & $p_2$ & $q_2$ & $r_2$ &  $s_2$ \\ 
  Method 3 & $p_3$ & $q_3$ & $r_3$ &  $s_3$ \\ 
  Method 4 & $p_4$ & $q_4$ & $r_4$ &  $s_4$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to *trim* the `\cmidrule` left or left and right, please also have a look at the manual or: [Set width of \cmidrule or \cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432030/277964)

But if you really want two rows, please see: [Break cell into multiple rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405130/277964)

Comment: I tested your code, it works very well. However, I need one more improvement.. I wish to place a short horizontal line separating Parameter C and the two subcolumns NPCR and UACR below.. can you kindly modify your code!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Dr.Sundar Despite this is a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/277964), I've this time added the information into my answer. (And I'm almost sure, that there are already questions about `\cline`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a genius! I shall use this model for future tables when I work on new papers. I am sure that it will be useful for those who regularly read this latex group for mastering their typesetting skills and professional use.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested @Jasper Habicht in his comment one way is to prescribe width of the last column so, that cells content will automatically split in two lines. I would use `m` column type instead of `p`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{22mm}|} 
    \hline
Name of the Method & Parameter $A$ & Parameter $B$ & Parameter $C$ \\ \hline
Proposed method & $p_0$ & $q_0$ & $NPCR: r_0$,  $UACR: s_0$ \\ \hline
Method 1 & $p_1$ & $q_1$ & $NPCR: r_1$,  $UACR: s_1$ \\ \hline
Method 2 & $p_2$ & $q_2$ & $NPCR: r_2$,  $UACR: s_2$ \\ \hline
Method 3 & $p_3$ & $q_3$ & $NPCR: r_3$,  $UACR: s_3$ \\ \hline
Method 4 & $p_4$ & $q_4$ & $NPCR: r_4$,  $UACR: s_4$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate document text border)

Another way is to use `tblr` of `tabularray` package for writing of your table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Comparison Table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c c c X[c, m]}
             } 

Name of the Method & Parameter $A$ & Parameter $B$ & Parameter $C$ \\
Proposed method & $p_0$ & $q_0$ & $NPCR: r_0$,  $UACR: s_0$ \\
Method 1 & $p_1$ & $q_1$ & $NPCR: r_1$,  $UACR: s_1$ \\
Method 2 & $p_2$ & $q_2$ & $NPCR: r_2$,  $UACR: s_2$ \\
Method 3 & $p_3$ & $q_3$ & $NPCR: r_3$,  $UACR: s_3$ \\
Method 4 & $p_4$ & $q_4$ & $NPCR: r_4$,  $UACR: s_4$ \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as before:

[image]